# Is it safe to uninstall SIMBL agent on Yosemite?

Tags: simbl

I'm running the most resent version of Yosemite and have noticed something called SIMBL Agent in the login items setting. I've tried to remove it but when I do it my computer locks up and I can't get rid of it. I've done some research into and I'm just wondering if someone knows how to get rid of it. I've read that it's something to do with Apple developers.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to uninstall SIMBL is to run the its bundled uninstaller.
You can get a copy from the [official website](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php).

After the uninstallation check if these folders are present:

- `~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL`
- `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL`

If they are present you can easily delete them.

Since OS X 10.11+ SIMBL gets broken due to the introduction of [SIP by Apple (System Integrity Protection)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

There is no need to disable SIP before the process and re-enable it later.

Comment: I was thinking of fresh installing the OS to get rid of SIMBL as I couldn't find an easier way. But this just worked. Saved me 3 hours.

Comment: @jason happy to help, if it worked please add a vote to the answer and question

Comment: Already upvoted the answer, now I upvoted the question as well.   

Comment: Catch-22, unfortunately the uninstaller now needs to be updated to work with the current osx.

Comment: The link to the website no longer works. I just migrated to Big Sur, and I'm getting SIMBL Agent crashes every 20-30 minutes in my user account, and every 5 minutes in my admin account.

Answer (score 0):

SIMBL is an app to "hack" (inject) code in OS X (eg: add plugins to the Finder etc).

If your computer is yours (not controled by an adminsys or you company (if relevant)) it should be safe to remove it.

And since latest version of OS X (10.11) is sort of broken due to the introduction of SIP by Apple (System Integrity Protection).

To uninstall SIMBL you can do the following

## Uninstall SIMBL on OS X 10.11

### Disable SIP

- Shutdown your computer
- Restart by holding cmd+r
- Start recovery partition
- Start “Terminal” from the menubar
- $ csrutil disable; reboot

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

### Uninstall SIMBL

$ locate SIMBL | sudo xargs rm -rf

Source: https://superuser.com/a/421002/381999

### Enable SIP back

- Shutdown your computer
- Restart by holding cmd+r
- Start recovery partition
- Start “Terminal” from the menubar
- $ csrutil enable; reboot

Et voilà! Now SIMBL and all plugins have been completely removed from your computer, and SIP is still enabled.

Comment: The 'Uninstall SIMBL" part of this answer is dangerous as there's no review of files before they are deleted.  While SIMBL is an unusual string so it may well be OK, it's still advisable to do `locate SIMBL | less` to review, before deleting the files.